# No matching function to call to

Tags: c++, функции, типы-данных

[image: Не могу понять в чем поблема]

Пробовала по-разному вводить - ничего не выходит

Comment: Здесь не журнал "Мурзилка", вопросы в картинках задавать не стоит. Есть текст...

Answer (score 1):

А что вы хотите? Описана функция как с первым параметром `int**`, а вы ей передаете `int[6][6]`, а это совершенно другое.

Вот компилятор и не знает, что же вызвать...

Comment: а как записать правильно?)

Comment: `renderString(int touchPointPosition[6][6],` и далее по тексту :)